# Why does Colorhug calibration with laptop and Linux Mint 17.1 come out very red?

Tags: color-management, display-calibration, linux, colorhug

I bought a ColorHug colorimter to calibrate my laptop's screen.

My laptop is a Asus [K53JE](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/K52JE/) running Linux Mint 17.1 (Ubuntu 14.04).

To calibrate the screen I plugged the colorhug and use Linux Mint built-in calibration software. The calibration process ending with success but the screen was very yellow/red.

So I removed the new profile and installed the [dispcamGUI software](http://dispcalgui.hoech.net/) and tried to calibrate the screen. It succeeded but screen was even more yellow/red than before.

The screen looks like in [this article](http://deaconmacmillan.blogspot.fr/2012/06/open-sourced-monitor-calibration-with.html).

I thought the ColorHUG might be calibrated before being sent to the end customers.
I haven't yet tried the liveCD than comes with the ColorHUG.

Since it's not possible to manually set laptop screen's settings (except the brightness)... 
Is it really possible to calibrate a Laptop's screen ?

Is there another way to calibrate a screen with the colorhug ?

Comment: Were you able to check the firmware? Did it help?

Comment: No I didn't have to even switch on my laptop, last week was crazy week. I'll keep you in touch when I'll have check the the firmware and try to calibrate using a matrice.

Answer (score 4):

There are actually three possibilities here.

First **and most likely, I think**, *make sure you have the latest colorhug firmware*. Run `colorhug-flash` to check. I have one of the very first colorhugs, and this red cast was common, but sometime in the last year a new firmware reduced this significantly.

Second, there's actually the possibility that *it's not as wrong as you think*. Blue-shifted screens seem more crisp and bright, and as consumers compare screens in stores, there is strong evolutionary pressure for screen's native look to be bluer and bluer. You may be very used to this from your pre-calibrated screen, and the adjusted output may actually be closer to right than your first impression due to that.

Third, you might get better results using a different calibration matrix from http://www.hughski.com/downloads/colorhug/ccmx/. There isn't one for your particular laptop, and they're *supposed* to be matched exactly, but you might have luck with one of the other Asus profiles.

Third-and-a-half: maybe there isn't an existing CCMX but needs to be. In that case, someone with a photospectrometer (a more sophisticated and expensive instrument than a colorimeter like the ColorHug) needs to produce one, [as outlined on the ColorHug site](http://www.hughski.com/calibrate.html).